# how to view a base64 encoded pdf in react js

Tags: reactjs, pdf, base64

The uploaded pdf file in my application is being stored as base64 encoding. I need to give a view pop-up for the same. I'm getting the base64 string along with the filetype, whether it's pdf or jpg/image. I have tried to convert the base64 string to blob as shown in many examples in stack overflow, but I am facing an error. `img` is the base64 string.

```
const byteCharacters = atob(img);
const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
 byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
 }
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
const blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/pdf"});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
this.setState({imgData:url})
```

In render this is what I have written:

```
<Document file={this.state.imgData}>
    <Page pageNumber={1} />
</Document>
```

But the image is not getting displayed and there isnt any error

When I'm pasting my base64 code in https://www.ipvoid.com/base64-to-pdf/
it's working. But why am I unable to view it? Is there any other alternate way?

Comment: Thanks for the reply....i have tried the above code.....and its not working like this also....im unable to view the pdf file.....i have used iframe inplace of document and tats also not working....there are no errors....but im nt able to view

Comment: Once the data is decoded, you will need to either convert it to image data for display or use a suitable JS control that is able to render this data on the page.  For example, the LEADTOOLS toolkit is a library has classes for [converting](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/co/rastercodecs-convert.html) the PDF data or [displaying](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/tutorials/html5-reactjs-display-files-in-the-document-viewer.html) it in a web browser using JS controls and a Document Service. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor).